# Reduce Android toolbar height using xml

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want my toolbar height reduced to 40dp, but the following code does not reflect the same:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: replace 40dp in layout_height

Comment: Toolbar as any other viewgroup element has it's own height and width ...so just changing the height will do the job..nothing magical!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing to this:

```
  android:layout_height="40dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_height="40dp"` instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Update your `Toolbar` XML as below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Hope this will help~